# Youtube modal popup close issues

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a youtube modal similar to this: https://www.udacity.com/ but in a wordpress that uses visual composer.

## I'm having 3 problems with this modal:

1-When clicked the background layer doesn't cover the top nav menu content, they still show up. How can I force the background to stretch and cover the menu?

2-The scrollbars are hidden but the user can still scroll down the wheel, and some elements from down the page are showing up on top of the popup layer

3-The biggest problem lies in closing the video and making the popup layers responsive.  The original code had fixed sizes, I changed to percentages and made it work but it looks very weird in mobile

### Link to the page:

http://blacktrax.cast-soft.com/lighting-test-2/

### CSS:

```
/* begining of master container for popup */

.mm-product-video-modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #03070D;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden; /* hides the scrollbar for the master container popup */
}


/* end of master container */

.mm-product-video-modal-container.open {
  display: block;
}

.mm-product-video-modal-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mm-product-video-modal-close {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000000000;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}


/* begining of video modal container*/
.mm-product-video-modal {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  max-height: 664px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -1000px; /* position where the video modal box is generated*/
  text-align: center; /* centralized video*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* end of video modal container */

.mm-product-video-modal.open {
  top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.mm-video-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mm-launch-container {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.mm-launch {
  border: none;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 5px 60px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.mm-launch-container p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mm-launch-container h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropper {
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

### Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
    width: 1180,
    height: 664,
    videoId: 'gZC1TOLVi60',
    events: {
      onReady: initialize
    }
  });
}
function initialize(){

}            

function deployVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').addClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').addClass('open');
    player.playVideo();
  }, 250);
}

function destroyVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').removeClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').removeClass('open');
    player.pauseVideo();
  }, 250);
}

jQuery('.mm-video-overlay').on('click', function() {
  destroyVideo();
});

jQuery('.mm-launch').on('click',function() {
  deployVideo();
});

</script>
```

### HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div align="center" class="mm-product-video-modal-container">
    <div class="mm-product-video-modal dropper">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div id="video-placeholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mm-video-overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="mm-launch-container container" align="center">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  <button class="mm-launch">Launch Video</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how the code is being inserted:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For problem 1:**

You need to set the header z-index to a lower value then the overlay. 
Add the following css class in the styles to overwrite header z-index.

```
header{
   z-index:1 !important;
}
```

Also adjust the z-index of the css class `mm-video-overlay` to 1001

```
.mm-video-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

**For problem 2:**

You need to use the property `overflow:hidden` on the body when the player overlay is shown and then remove it when video overlay is closed.

Code to use in js:

```
function deployVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').addClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').addClass('open');
    player.playVideo();
  }, 250);
  jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}

function destroyVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').removeClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').removeClass('open');
    player.pauseVideo();
  }, 250);
  jQuery('body').css('overflow','');
}
```

This will take care of the scroll issue

**For problem 3:**

Set the top property in percentage of the css class `mm-product-video-modal.open` to 15%

```
.mm-product-video-modal.open {
   top: 15%;
   margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Solution for problem 1 worked. 
Solution for problem 2 and 3 didn't work. I opened the console and it said that $ was not recognized - 
blacktrax.cast-soft.com/:329 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)

Comment: Oh sorry. Please replace the $ with jQuery

Comment: For problem 3 can you share a screenshot?

Comment: What i noticed (chrome) is that the video play overlay was cutting if it got small so hence gave the fix for top margin. Can you explain "The biggest problem lies in closing the video and making the popup layers responsive."

Comment: Sure Nasir! I think is although it looks like it's working is not a good experience. I noticed that Udacity ( https://www.udacity.com/ ) forces the video for full screen when it's mobile. This is the screenshot :http://imgur.com/a/RuLf6  . So it's happening just like you said, it gets cut. Another thing is happening is that on chrome android the video takes a while to download while works fine in android firefox. I noticed that the Z index problem comes back on both android browsers: http://imgur.com/a/MQDpI

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this:

FULL HTML CODE:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div align="center" class="mm-product-video-modal-container">
    <div class="mm-product-video-modal dropper">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div id="video-placeholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mm-video-overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="mm-launch-container container" align="center">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  <button class="mm-launch">Watch the video</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

FULL JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
    width: 1180,
    height: 664,
    videoId: 'gZC1TOLVi60',
    events: {
      onReady: initialize
    }
  });
}
function initialize(){

}            

function deployVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').addClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').addClass('open');
    player.playVideo();
  }, 250);
  jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}

function destroyVideo() {
  jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal').removeClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mm-product-video-modal-container').removeClass('open');
    player.pauseVideo();
  }, 250);
  jQuery('body').css('overflow','');
}

jQuery('.mm-video-overlay').on('click', function() {
  destroyVideo();
});

jQuery('.mm-launch').on('click',function() {
  deployVideo();
});

</script>
```

However I still have 2 problems with this code.

1-After reading the documentation and considering that I'm totally newbie in Javascript / Jquery, I could not add put the playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 2 } to the function function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady

PARTIAL JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
    width: 1180,
    height: 664,
    videoId: 'gZC1TOLVi60',
    playerVars: { 'controls':2 },
    events: {
      onReady: initialize
    }
  });
}
```

Note: for some reason controls in playerVars don't work, I've tried 0,1,2 and nothing works to show up the controls

2-For some reason the video is still running on the background when you close it, it should stop or reset to the beginning when you close the dialog